# How to use `autoSchemaFile` only for one resolver in nestjs

Tags: graphql, nestjs

It is possible allow auto schema file generation (`autoSchemaFile`) in nestjs only for one resolver?

I would like to have one autogenerated scheme and rest of is written manually.

Thank you.